# server not reading array from body

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose, axios

I have created an API to post some data and store it in MongoDB using mongoose and one of its fields is an array. I am sending an array as a string and array as plain  ( tried both ) in payload but that field is undefined on the server and not able to read due to some reason and getting undefined for that image the posting is working and I can save stuff on MongoDB but that one array field is always empty.

my request payload :

```
{
    "name" :"name" 
    ,"description" :"description" 
    ,"price" :123 
    ,"image_array" : "['image','image2']" 
    ,"category" :"category" 
    ,"country" :"country" 
    ,"city" :"city" 
    ,"thumbnail" :"thumbnail" 
}
```

my response:
200 OK

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "name",
        "description": "description",
        "price": 123,
        "thumbnail": "thumbnail",
        "images": [],
        "category": "category",
        "country": "country",
        "city": "city",
        "user": "633710ae6238121bd9ff4f46",
        "status": "active",
        "likes": 0,
        "_id": "633c794ef9449f8b86c948b0",
        "createdAt": "2022-10-04T18:19:58.440Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-10-04T18:19:58.440Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "message": "Product added successfully",
    "Array_type": "undefined"
}
```

route:

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("post product");
  try {
    const new product = new Product({
      name: req.body.name,
      description: req.body.description,
      price: req.body.price,
      image: req.body.image,
      category: req.body.category,
      country: req.body.country,
      city: req.body.city,
      user: req.user._id,
      thumbnail: req.body.thumbnail,
    });

    data = await new product.save();
    res.status(200).json({
      data,
      message: "Product added successfully",
      Array_type: type of req.body.images,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

product schema

```
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    thumbnail: { type: String, required: true },
    images: [String],
    category: { type: String, required: true },
    country: { type: String },
    city: { type: String },
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    status: { type: String, default: "active" },
    likes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

Comment: in  your request payload, when you try "image_array": ['image1', 'image2'] in your payload and console req.body.images, do you get undefined? What do you see on the server?

Comment: yes i get undefined

Comment: yes i am getting  = > ['image','image2']

Comment: How are you creating that request payload? It looks like you're trying to use JSON but it's not valid

Answer (score 0):

Your request payload is not valid for the `image_array` array. All you've sent is a string literal that looks sort of like an array.

In short, never manually create JSON. Always use built-in serialisation tools like [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```js
const product = {
  name: "name",
  description: "description",
  price: 123,
  images: ["image", "image2"], // just a normal array
  category: "category",
  country: "country",
  city: "city",
  thumbnail: "thumbnail",
};

const res = await fetch("/", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(product),
  headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
});

// or if using Axios

const res = await axios.post("/", product);
```

---

On the server side, make sure you use `req.body.images` to set the `images` property...

```js
images: req.body.images,
```

or more easily just use all `req.body` properties

```js
const new product = new Product(req.body);
```